# iPhone: Blur UIImage

Tags: iphone, image-manipulation, quartz-2d

In my iPhone application I have a black-and-white `UIImage`. I need to blur that image (Gaussian blur would do).

iPhone clearly knows how to blur images, as [it does that when it draws shadows](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadows/dq_shadows.html).

However I did not found anything related in the API.

Do I have to do blurring by hand, without hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 15):

Try this (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528726/does-ios-5-support-blur-coreimage-fiters)):

```
@interface UIImage (ImageBlur)
- (UIImage *)imageWithGaussianBlur;
@end

@implementation UIImage (ImageBlur)
- (UIImage *)imageWithGaussianBlur {
    float weight[5] = {0.2270270270, 0.1945945946, 0.1216216216, 0.0540540541, 0.0162162162};
    // Blur horizontally
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size);
    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModePlusLighter alpha:weight[0]];
    for (int x = 1; x < 5; ++x) {
        [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(x, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModePlusLighter alpha:weight[x]];
        [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(-x, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModePlusLighter alpha:weight[x]];
    }
    UIImage *horizBlurredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    // Blur vertically
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size);
    [horizBlurredImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModePlusLighter alpha:weight[0]];
    for (int y = 1; y < 5; ++y) {
        [horizBlurredImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, y, self.size.width, self.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModePlusLighter alpha:weight[y]];
        [horizBlurredImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, -y, self.size.width, self.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModePlusLighter alpha:weight[y]];
    }
    UIImage *blurredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    //
    return blurredImage;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
UIImage *blurredImage = [originalImage imageWithGaussianBlur];
```

To get stronger blur just apply this effect twice or more :)

Answer (score 6):

After having the same problem by the past, check this lib:

https://github.com/tomsoft1/StackBluriOS

Very easy to use also:

```
UIImage *newIma=[oldIma stackBlur:radius];
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider approaching the job via CIFilter:

[Developing Core Image Filters for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#515)

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no a straight forward API to implement the blur effect. You need to process the pixels to accomplish that.

iPhone draw shadows by means of gradient and not through blurring.

Answer (score 0):

To blur an image, you would use a convolution matrix. Here is the [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664168/iphone-image-processing-matrix-convolution) to apply a convolution matrix, and here is an [overview of convolution matrices](http://pippin.gimp.org/image_processing/chap_area.html) as well as some sample matrices (including blur and gaussian blur).