# UITableViewCell blurred background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I want my table view to have a blurred white background.

You will see some examples of the table view blur (Siri and Twitter) in this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hsEUBLIJvmE&feature=player_embedded

I have tried to use the gaussian blur from this question (it is the second answer) : [iPhone: Blur UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356250/iphone-blur-uiimage)

But when I apply this to a white there is no blur applied... do I need to create this on photoshop myself?

Thank you!

Comment: Those blurs were to a photo. You cannot obviously blur an image consisting of a single color, so what is your real problem? You may be able to use a core image filter now to do this - it fairly new to iOS.

Comment: Thanks, I know Core Image Filtering.. I will read the documentation briefly and take that approach