# Gaussian Blur an UIImageView (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been searching for this, but i was not able to find a correct answer.

I wanna make a button, and if you press on this button, an image view will be blurred with a gaussian blur.

How can i do that?

Comment: OSX? iOS? What version? What have you tried? etc. etc? Is Core Image a solution?

Comment: Google, please find information on 'ios image gaussian blur.'

Comment: UIImageView should be iOS

Comment: uiimage view in ios off course

Answer (score 8):

You could use [StackBluriOS](https://github.com/tomsoft1/StackBluriOS) or [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

or

Try this (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528726/does-ios-5-support-blur-coreimage-fiters)): Answer from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9148397/1578508)

```
@interface UIImage (ImageBlur)
- (UIImage *)imageWithGaussianBlur;
@end

@implementation UIImage (ImageBlur)
- (UIImage *)imageWithGaussianBlur {
    float weight[5] = {0.2270270270, 0.1945945946, 0.1216216216, 0.0540540541, 0.0162162162};
    // Blur horizontally
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size);
    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModePlusLighter alpha:weight[0]];
    for (int x = 1; x < 5; ++x) {
        [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(x, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModePlusLighter alpha:weight[x]];
        [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(-x, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModePlusLighter alpha:weight[x]];
    }
    UIImage *horizBlurredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    // Blur vertically
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size);
    [horizBlurredImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModePlusLighter alpha:weight[0]];
    for (int y = 1; y < 5; ++y) {
        [horizBlurredImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, y, self.size.width, self.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModePlusLighter alpha:weight[y]];
        [horizBlurredImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, -y, self.size.width, self.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModePlusLighter alpha:weight[y]];
    }
    UIImage *blurredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    //
    return blurredImage;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
UIImage *blurredImage = [originalImage imageWithGaussianBlur];
```

To get stronger blur just apply this effect twice or more :)

Comment: Did you try it standalone? So just set a blurred image although if no button is pressed? Did you try all Options?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a CoreImage Framework([Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/index.html)), or any third party framework such as GPUImage([Github Page](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)). Gaussian Blur is available in CoreImage(iOS) only starting from iOS 6. Of course you can use any other solutions, but the proper "filtering" is done with those frameworks.

Comment: go for this https://github.com/lukabernardi/LBBlurredImage